# How to sync time of my application with device time

Tags: android

I was making an alarm application. So I would like to know the code for synchronizing my device time with the application time. What would the code be for synchronization of time?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It's unclear from your description what exactly you are trying to do.  Your application runs on the device, right?  Are you asking how to get the time from the device or is this something more complicated like synchronizing time between two devices?

Comment: I want to get time from the device.

Answer (score 0):

```
CountDownTimer newtimer = new CountDownTimer(1000000000, 1000) { 

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            String currentTime = c.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        }
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    };
    newtimer.start();
```

Using above code, you will get current time from system every second. Put this code into a service and use this time in your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making an *alarm clock* app, Android has a system service for this; [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). There is a [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) on how to use the class as well.

Directly from the tutorial, you can get the singleton instance of `AlarmManager` as follows.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

The tutorial also uses the old `Calendar` class to set the date and time for the alarm, but I would recommend using the newer [`java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary.html) classes, as they are much easier to work with. These classes are [available on Android O](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#rt) (API Level 26), or as a back port to older versions with the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library.

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(year, month, dayOfMonth, hour, minute, 0 , 0, ZoneId.systemDefault());
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateTime.toEpochSecond(), pendingIntent);
```

---

Though, if you are just interested in getting the current system time, you can use the following method with `java.time`.

```
ZonedDateTime current = ZonedDateTime.now();
```

Or using the following method otherwise.

```
Long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
```